# Powershell Help. Can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: powershell

I am trying to look up all User Objects in an AD OU, grab their "Company" attribute, then use that value to find a group with its value equal to "company", grab that groups' description field, and overwrite the original User's information started at Department's field.  I would like to do this for all users of a specific group. Here is the code i have (I did not write this):

```
$OU = "(name=OUTest)"
$DN = (get-adorganizationalunit -ldapfilter $name).distinguishedName
$users = get-aduser -searchbase $DN -filter * -properties *
foreach ($user in $users) {
$groupNameDesc = (get-adgroup $user.company).Description; 
set-aduser $user -description $groupNameDesc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show has some issues:

- The ldap filter syntax is wrong. Find info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)
- you are trying to get ALL properties from the user objects, where you only need a few
- there is no test if a group is found before setting the users description property

This should help:

```
$OUName = 'TheNameForTheOU'

# instead of the -Filter parameter, you can also use -LdapFilter "(name=$OUName)"
$DN = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq '$OUName'").DistinguishedName

# find user objects inside the OU and take just the properties you need
# property DistinguishedName is always returned.
Get-ADUser -SearchBase $DN -Filter * -properties Company, Description | ForEach-Object {
    # try and find the group by that name
    $group = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq $($_.Company)" -Properties Description -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($group) {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Department $group.Description -WhatIf
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find a group called $($_.Company)"
    }
}
```

The `-WhatIf` switch has the code simply write out to console what *would* happen. No users description property is actually updated. Once you are satisfied with the info shown in the console, remove the `-WhatIf`.

Comment: I tried this and the record does not update as well.  I "think" after parsing it that it was because it's trying to update the users description instead of department, but updating that did not seem to fix it.

Comment: @Vaedur Sorry, my bad. The Description property is not returned by default for `Get-ADGroup`, so we need to ask for it. Fixed in the code now.

Comment: O.k... So the only issue was the -properties Company, Description should be Company, Department.. I made that change..and.. it worked..omg.. So someone plans on handing me the org chart to make sure that the users department matches the users company code.. and this script will save me like 4-8 hours of work 1x a month.  Like seriously helpful...